# Memcached is not working with AWS Classic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

My application is running on two EC2 instances and I installed memcached on both the server. When i have checked with IP, memcached is working fine as per the requirement. But when I attached classic load balancer and attached 2 instance in that load balancer, the Memcached related functionality stop working.
But If I attached single server in load balancer then Its works fine.
The problem comes only when I attached 2 EC2 instances in Load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `memcached` memory is shared between both EC2 instances. If you don't want to share memory then make sure that `Stickiness` is enabled in the load balancer. refer below image.

[image]